# How to get SVG element dimensions in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, svg

In most browsers, the following would work.

```
window.onload = function(){
    console.log( document.getElementById('svgElm').getBoundingClientRect().width );
};
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/arisav/4/edit). If you try it in Google Chrome, the console will output `200`. However, FireFox returns `0`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've ended up falling back to the parent dimensions if SVG properties cannot be returned. Here  is a demo http://jsbin.com/uzoyik/1/edit.

The relavent code is:

```
svg.clientWidth || svg.parentNode.clientWidth
svg.clientHeight || svg.parentNode.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't think "width" is a standard cross-browser property of the object returned by the  getBoundingClientRect method. I typically do something like:

```
var box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
var width = box.right-box.left;
var height = box.bottom-box.top;
```

Answer (score 2):

This Firefox bug was fixed in Firefox 33 which was released on 14 October 2014.

See [bug 530985](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530985) for details.

Comment: As of right now in FF 65.0.1 (64-bit), clientWidth and clientHeight for svg elements always return 0 for me.  This is not the case with Chrome.  However getBoundingClientRect().width/height does seem to work.  Why is this?

According to MDN:
The Element.clientWidth property is zero for inline elements and elements with no CSS; otherwise, it's the inner width of an element in pixels.

However even applying css does not get clientWidth/Height to work, and it doesn't seem to be an inline.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found for this was to use `.getComputedStyle()`. And since `svg` elements are not supported in old IE8- browsers, `.getComputedStyle()` is the way to give consistent results.

So I ended up using this function in my library:

```
var heightComponents = ['height', 'paddingTop', 'paddingBottom', 'borderTopWidth', 'borderBottomWidth'],
    widthComponents = ['width', 'paddingLeft', 'paddingRight', 'borderLeftWidth', 'borderRightWidth'];

var svgCalculateSize = function (el) {

    var gCS = window.getComputedStyle(el), // using gCS because IE8- has no support for svg anyway
        bounds = {
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        };

    heightComponents.forEach(function (css) { 
        bounds.height += parseFloat(gCS[css]);
    });
    widthComponents.forEach(function (css) {
        bounds.width += parseFloat(gCS[css]);
    });
    return bounds;
};
```