# d3: Scale force layout graph to be fully visible within SVG on initialization

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scale

I created a d3 force layout and I take data from different sources. Sometimes there may be 20 nodes, sometimes 600 - it varies with each dataset. The thing i would like to do is to make a uniform way for the layout to be fully visible when it is initially loaded. Of course the user can afterwards zoom/drag/pan, but I would like him to see the full layout when it is initially loaded.

This is the size of my svg, and the example sizes of possible datasets.
[image: Current situation]

This is how I would like to see it when it starts. the whole dataset should be visible within the SVG.
[image: What i need]
Right now i'm trying to achieve this by checking how many nodes there are within a dataset, and scale down the 'g' element which contains them. This, however, i feel is a pretty clumsy way of doing it, plus it gives me some bugs when dragging. See code below.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

```
   var width = 1200,
        height = 800;

    var min_zoom = 0.5;
    var max_zoom = 10;
    var scale = 0.5;

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .translate([100,50])
        .scale(scale)
        .scaleExtent([min_zoom,max_zoom]);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

    var force = cola.d3adaptor()
       .linkDistance(130)
       .avoidOverlaps(true)
       //.jaccardLinkLengths(40, 0.7)
       .handleDisconnected(false)
      .size([700, 500]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(zoom.on("zoom", zoomed));
        //.attr("transform","scale(1)");

    var g = svg.append("g")
                .attr("id", "gelem")
                .attr("transform", "translate(100,50)");

     force
          .nodes(nodes)
          .links(links)
          .groups(groups);


          nodes.forEach(function (node){
            node.height = 60;
            node.width = 60;
          })

          force.start(5,5,5);

     var group = g.selectAll(".group")
                .data(groups)
              .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("rx", 8).attr("ry", 8)
                //.classed("group", true)
                .attr("class", "group")
                .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); });
                //.call(force.drag);

      var link = g.selectAll(".link")
          .data(links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });


      var node = g.selectAll(".node")
          .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node");
          //.call(force.drag);

      node.append("image")
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return "../icons/"+d.type+".png";})
          .attr("x", -25)
          .attr("y", -25)
          .attr("width", 50)
          .attr("height", 50);

     function scaleContainer(nodes){
            if (nodes.length>200){ scale = 0.6;}
            if (nodes.length>400){ scale = 0.4;}
            if (nodes.length>500) { scale = 0.3;}
             //var height = document.getElementById("gelem").getBBox().height;
             //var width = document.getElementById("gelem").getBBox().width;
             //console.log("w/h of g element: " + height + ', '+ width);
             //console.log("g transform" ,g.attr("transform"));
             g.attr("transform", "translate(100,50) scale(" + scale + ")");
             console.log("svg scale2", g.attr("transform"));
          }

          scaleContainer(nodes);
function zoomed() {
    console.log("translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236600/d3-js-force-layout-auto-zoom-scale-after-loading you checked that out ? The bottom answer that uses getbbox()

Comment: @thisOneGuy I finally managed to do it, exactly thanks to the answer you told me about! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: no problem :) glad i could help