# D3.js not showing in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js

I can not run this visualization on firefox, while I can do it on Chrome and even on Edge :

https://naustud.io/tech-stack/

Since I was very inspired by it and wanted to analyze it - I am a beginner with d3.js -, the fact that this visualization can not be rendered on all browsers is a bit of a drag on my approach. .

Does anyone have an explanation? Can this be solved? Thank you everyone.

Comment: funny, ff can't even open mentioned website. it freezes ff. I had to force quit it.

Comment: I know, on my linux' firefox it loads everything, just not showing, but in Windows' firefox it freezes.. In both OS, it works fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in Firefox, the `clientWidth` of the svg element isn't being read, possibly related to this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874811. Instead the `width` variable is being set to 0, and that looks like it causes infinite recursion when trying to pack the chart.

To correct this, you can use `.node().parentNode.clientWidth` (via [How to get SVG element dimensions in FireFox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122790/how-to-get-svg-element-dimensions-in-firefox)), by adding this before the `console.log` in **techstack-main.js** (Line 490):

```
if (!width) {
  width = svg.node().parentNode.clientWidth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the right documentation and it's very informative. I am now able to bypass the issue.

Comment: I'm trying this now too, but if his answer solved the issue you posted about, proper etiquette would be to mark his answer as accepted.